# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns false after login while using OpenId Connect with Auth0

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, openid-connect, auth0

I am trying to implement user authentication in an ASP.Net Core (v2.1) MVC application using OpenId Connect and Auth0. I have the required configurations stored in the AppSettings files and application runs well till the Auth0 login page comes. Post login it hits the Callback URL which basically invokes a method (method name is Callback) in my Account Controller. In the callback method I am trying to get the access token if the user is authenticated. However, the User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns false. Here is my code in the Startup.cs file--

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Set Cookie Policy
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    // Add authentication services
    services.AddAuthentication(options => {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOpenIdConnect("Auth0", options => {
        options.Authority = $"https://{Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}";
        options.ClientId = Configuration["Auth0:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Auth0:ClientSecret"];
        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/oauth/callback");
        options.ClaimsIssuer = "Auth0";
        options.SaveTokens = true;

        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            // handle the logout redirection 
            OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = (context) =>
            {
                var logoutUri = $"https://{Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}/v2/logout?client_id={Configuration["Auth0:ClientId"]}";

                var postLogoutUri = context.Properties.RedirectUri;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postLogoutUri))
                {
                    if (postLogoutUri.StartsWith("/"))
                    {
                        // transform to absolute
                        var request = context.Request;
                        postLogoutUri = request.Scheme + "://" + request.Host + request.PathBase + postLogoutUri;
                    }
                    logoutUri += $"&returnTo={ Uri.EscapeDataString(postLogoutUri)}";
                }

                context.Response.Redirect(logoutUri);
                context.HandleResponse();

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

And here is my code in the Account Controller

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public async Task Login(string returnUrl = "/")
    {
        await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("Auth0", new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = returnUrl });
    }

    [Authorize]
    public async Task Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Auth0", new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = Url.Action("Index", "Home")
        });
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    public IActionResult AccessDenied()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Claims()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("/oauth/callback")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> CallbackAsync()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Claims", "Account");
    }
}
```

Please help. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Amit Anand

Answer (score 1):

In fact i'm not sure why your custom `CallbackAsync` method fires during OIDC login .  The callback url of OIDC middleware will handle token valiation ,token decode,exchange token and finally fill the user principle . You shouldn't handle the process and let OIDC middlware handle it , so change the route of the `CallbackAsync` method(or change the `CallbackPath` in OIDC middleware , but of course the url should match the url config in Auth0's portal ) , for example : `[Route("/oauth/callbackAfterLogin")]` .

After change that , the process will be : user will be redirect to Auth0 for login -->Auth0 validate the user's credential and redirect user back to url `https://localhost:xxx/oauth/callback`-->OIDC middlware handle token --> authentication success . If you want to redirect to `CallbackAsync`(route is `/oauth/callbackAfterLogin`) and get tokens there , you can directly pass the url in `ChallengeAsync` method when login :

```
await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("Auth0", 
     new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/oauth/callbackAfterLogin"});
```